# Webview webpage + Video or Youtube

Tags: xamarin, webview

I recently found a digital billboard project called DisplayMonkey, which shows me digital content such as: images, videos, html, etc. The problem is that when you show a YouTube video or any other media this does not automatically reproduce.

To which I refer, the project that I use that would be the Display, shows me in html file all the content that I have and does it in a random way, when it comes to the video it does not reproduce it.

Need autoplay youtube or alternative server videos
The web page that the display shows me is the following:

http://display-dev.cclcloud.co
user: test
password: 2019**

Any opinion on how you should do this? html + js code pure?

I have tried several alternatives and it has not worked for me, need help, thanks

Comment: What is the problem you want to reproduce, it seems that there is no clear explanation in the question.

Comment: I have a web page that shows img, video, etc,. I want the webview to be able to play the video automatically.

Comment: The video tag in the general web page has the autoplay attribute set, but if it is a third-party video address, it may not be automatically played successfully.You can show code of webview or html.